# Make PowerShell recommendation like Linux-bash (E.g. docker)

Tags: docker, powershell, autocomplete, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tab-completion

I have windows 10 OS with WSL enabled and docker for windows installed.

When I type docker in PowerShell and hit tab, it suggests me with the corresponding folders and files in my working directory.

*here AndroidStudioProjects is a directory in my working directory.*
[image]

On the other hand,
When I type docker in WSL Ubuntu and hit tab, it suggests the available docker commands themselves. (My expected behavior)
[image]

**I want PowerShell to also recommend like WSL ubuntu.**

Comment: Are you sure that this isn't a difference in the implementation of the `docker` command between the two environments?

Comment: What happens if you install pwsh (PowerShell 7) in WSL and then try to launch the WSL docker from within pwsh?

Comment: Default display configuration settings are preset, you can change the xml files to display just like this. Its not dangerous either, as long as you specify it specifically for what you need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably:

- `docker` on WSL comes with tab-completion for *POSIX-compatible shells* such as `bash`, installed via the shell's initialization files.
- no such support is provided for *PowerShell*, but there are third-party solutions - see below.

---

**Installing PowerShell tab-completion for `docker`:**

Install the [`DockerCompletion` module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/DockerCompletion/) from the PowerShell Gallery:

```
# Install the module in the scope of the current user.
Install-Module DockerCompletion -Scope CurrentUser

# Import the module into the session.
# Add this line to your $PROFILE file to make the tab-completion
# available in future sessions.
Import-Module DockerCompletion
```

---

**Installing PowerShell tab-completion for *all supported* programs (CLIs):**

The [`posh-cli` meta-module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/posh-cli/) - whose repo is [here](https://github.com/bergmeister/posh-cli) - offers a convenient way to **automatically install tab-completion support for all locally installed CLIs for which application-specific tab-completion modules are available**:

```
# Install the meta-module in the scope of the current user.
Install-Module posh-cli -Scope CurrentUser

# This looks for locally installed CLIs for which tab-completion
# modules are available, installs them, and adds
# Import-Module commands to your $PROFILE file.
Install-TabCompletion
```

See [the README](https://github.com/bergmeister/posh-cli/blob/master/README.md) for more information.